# HTML form submit content with PHP to .txt file - blank?

Tags: php, html, forms

I created a HTML form which should submit the inputted text into a .txt file with PHP, but it only creates a blank line and I don't know what the issue is.

Help is greatly appreciated!

```
<form class="form-inline validate" name="form1" method="post" action="signup.php" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" value="" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Subscribe to our newsletter" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" name="Submit">
        </div>

    </div>
</form>

<?php

$username = $_POST['user'];

//the data

$data = "$email\n";

//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);

//close the file

fclose($fh);
print "User Submitted";

?>
```

Comment: First thing to do would be add an `<input name="user">` element (or not look for `$_POST['user']`). You should also (probably) get `$email` from `$_POST['mail']`. It's kind of hard to make sense of your code

Comment: As per what @Phil said, plus wrap your executable code around a conditional statement if your entire code is inside the same file, an `isset()` along with your named submit button and `empty()` for the input. Doing it as such and on page load, will immediately write to your file with a blank entry.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which will trigger an Undefined index warning. Plus, you're also using the wrong variable to write with. `$username = $_POST['user'];` and `$data = "$email\n";`

Comment: *Teach a man how to fish...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get mail change your php code to

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
       $email = $_POST['mail'];

      //the data

      $data = "$email\n";

      //open the file and choose the mode

      $fh = fopen("users.txt", "a+");
      fwrite($fh, $data);

      //close the file

      fclose($fh);
      print "User Submitted";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: That'll help, but there will still be a blank line between entries because the PHP code is executed when the form is displayed as well as when it is submitted.